# Runtime error when calling a REST service that returns List<String> deployed in WebLogic

Tags: java, json, weblogic

I'm deploying a REST service written in Java on WebLogic.
The method I'm interested in has this signature:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/myway/mock")
public List<String> getMyMock(@QueryParam("pic") String pic, @QueryParam("year") int year)
```

After I deploy this service to WebLogic I'm calling it from curl or Postman and I see this error in WebLogic logs:

*<org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor>  <MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, ***type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<java.lang.String>***.>
Feb 02, 2024 4:09:22 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<java.lang.String>.*

If I return just a String from this method, it works fine. Only when I try to return List I have this issue. I guess it is due to the fact that WebLogic can't figure out how to return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON from List, but there must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Json serializer in the classpath. Try adding this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the main pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.28</version>
</dependency>
```